# Trying to filter an array of objects based on several fields in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First of all, my apologies if my question is too obvious but I my knowledge is limited and I don't get how to achieve what I am trying. I have a JSON file as source of the data (songs) and I am trying to filter that data based on several fields (level, name, artist, etc.).

Example of some data from the JSON:

```
[
  {"artist": "Black",
    "categories": "Arreglos",
    "date": 1639127185000,
    "level": "Fácil",
    "musicStyle": "Pop/Rock",
    "name": "Wonderful Life",
    "practice": "n/a",
    "preloadID": "Wonderful_Life",
    "subtitle": "Fácil",
  },
{"artist": "",
    "categories": "Arreglos",
    "date": 1587948049309,
    "image": "./images/arreglos/a_million_dreams.jpeg",
    "level": "Fácil",
    "musicStyle": "Film/TV",
    "name": "A million dreams",
    "preloadID": "AMillionDreams_Facil",
    "subtitle": "Fácil",
  },
{"artist": "",
    "categories": "Arreglos",
    "date": 1587948046688,
    "image": "./images/arreglos/a_million_dreams.jpeg",
    "level": "Principiante",
    "musicStyle": "Film/TV",
    "name": "A million dreams",
    "preloadID": "AMillionDreams_Principiante",
    "subtitle": "Principiante",
  },
{"artist": "Vanessa Carlton",
    "categories": "Arreglos",
    "date": 1602939064030,
    "level": "Fácil",
    "musicStyle": "Pop/Rock",
    "name": "A thousand miles",
    "preloadID": "AThousandMiles_Facil",
    "subtitle": "Fácil",
  },
{"artist": "Vanessa Carlton",
    "categories": "Arreglos",
    "date": 1602939064033,
    "level": "Muy fácil",
    "musicStyle": "Pop/Rock",
    "name": "A thousand miles",
    "preloadID": "AThousandMiles_MuyFacil",
    "subtitle": "Muy fácil",
    "tonality": ""
  },
]
```

And this is the script I have to try to filter the data.

```
let filteredItems = [];
let filterLevel=this.context.appActions.dataSlots['ds_LevelFilter'];
let filterStr=this.context.appActions.dataSlots['ds_SearchFilter'];
filterStr=filterStr.toLowerCase();
      
      items.forEach(item => {
        if (item["artist"].toLowerCase().includes(filterStr) || item["name"].toLowerCase().includes(filterStr) ) {
          filteredItems.push(item);
          }
      });
      
      items.forEach(item => {
        if (item["level"] == filterLevel) {
          filteredItems.push(item);
        }
      });
      
      items = filteredItems.sort((a, b) => {
              return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
            }).slice(0,this.context.appActions.dataSlots['ds_limitQuery']);

return items;
```

For filterStr, I have a text field where the user would write a search and if that is included in name or artist, it should return the resulted documents.

In filterLevel I have a picker with several values (Easy, Medium, etc. in Spanish) and it should be equal to the field "level" from the data.

I am not sure if the code shows what I am trying but if I use just the first if block (name and artist) it works perfectly. But if I add the second, it gives me an error of duplicated keys (it is a React project). I am guessing the script is not correct.

Comment: probably add another `|| item["level"] == filterLevel` to the first `forEach` and remove the second

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried to add that and for some reason it does not filter with "level" but it does with the other two fields. The snippet of code is:items.forEach(item => {
        if (item["artist"].toLowerCase().includes(filterStr) 
            || item["name"].toLowerCase().includes(filterStr)
            || item["level"] == filterLevel) {
             filteredItems.push(item);
          }
      });

Comment: please post sample data for `filterStr`, `filterLevel`, `items` and expected output

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the first post to include more info and details about filterStr and filterLevel. I hope it is better now.

Comment: JSON is a text format. You do not have JSON there, only an array of objects. Using the correct terminology aids in searching for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an Object filter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```js
const songs = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Golden Hour',
    artist: 'Kacey Musgraves',
    level: "Fácil",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'King Size Manger',
    artist: 'Josh Turner',
    level: "Fácil",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Legend',
    artist: 'Bob Marley',
    level: "Muy fácil",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Catch A Fire',
    artist: 'Bob Marley',
    level: "Muy fácil",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Fine Line',
    artist: 'Harry Styles',
    level: "Fácil",
  },
]

function filterSongs(filterStr = '', filterLevel = '') {

  return songs.filter(item => {
    const context = filterStr.toLowerCase()
    // Filter on level else ignore by always returning true.
    let result = filterLevel.length ? (item.level === filterLevel) : true
    
    // If result is false because level was set and did not match then skip filterStr check.
    // If result is true because level was ignored or matched then search if filterStr has value.
    if(result && filterStr.length) {
      result = item.artist.toLowerCase().includes(context) || item.name.toLowerCase().includes(context)
    }
    
    return result

  })

}

console.log('Search for Harry', filterSongs('Harry'))

console.log('Search for level Fácil', filterSongs('', 'Fácil'))

console.log('Search for Golden with level Fácil', filterSongs('Golden', 'Fácil'))

console.log('Search for Bob', filterSongs('Bob'))
```

How to implement the above code with your example:

```js
let filterLevel = this.context.appActions.dataSlots['ds_LevelFilter'] ?? '';
let filterStr = this.context.appActions.dataSlots['ds_SearchFilter'] ?? '';
let filterLimit = this.context.appActions.dataSlots['ds_limitQuery'] ?? 15;

function filterSongs(filterStr = '', filterLevel = '') {

  return songs.filter(item => {
    const context = filterStr.toLowerCase()
    // Filter on level else ignore by always returning true.
    let result = filterLevel.length ? (item.level === filterLevel) : true
    
    // If result is false because level was set and did not match then skip filterStr check.
    // If result is true because level was ignored or matched then search if filterStr has value.
    if(result && filterStr.length) {
      result = item.artist.toLowerCase().includes(context) || item.name.toLowerCase().includes(context)
    }
    
    return result

  })

}

let filteredItems = filterSongs(filterStr, filterLevel)

return filteredItems.sort((a, b) => {
  return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
}).slice(0,filterLimit);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It seems to be the right path to take but as I am ashamed to say that my knowledge is so limited that I don't get to fit the function into my snippet. In my project, the variable "items" must contain at the end the array with the result but I am not capable to get it done mixing your suggestion with my scenario. How can I get the variable items to contain the result of the filtering if there is some values as input in filterStr or filterLevel?

Comment: @petoma Added implementation example to the end of my answer for you.

Comment: Thank you so much Marc! I just tried that changing a few things and it works wonderfully! I marked the answer as the working one and upvoted the answer. I am not very familiar with this forum so I am sorry if my question was not accurate. I keep learning in the way. Thanks again!

Comment: One more question if I may. If I want to add an additional filter like "musicStyle" to the function?